# Ajax Popup Windows not loading while configuring ssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, nginx

I am working with Ruby on Rails,Using nginx as web server and unicorn as application server. I tried to configure ssl for my application and Its works perfectly. The nginx configuration I used is giving below.

```
upstream unicorn_domain {
  # This is the socket we configured in unicorn.rb
 server unix:/home/ubuntu/root_path/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=30;
 }
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name demo.domain.com;
      rewrite ^ https://demo.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
      }
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name demo.domain.com;
    ssl                   on;
    ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com_chain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols         SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers           ALL:-ADH:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP;
    ssl_session_cache     shared:SSL:10m;


    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Location of our static files
    root /home/ubuntu/root_path/public;
    access_log /home/ubuntu/root_path/log/nginx/nginx.access.log;
    location / {


        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # If you don't find the filename in the static files
        # Then request it from the unicorn server
       if (!-f $request_filename) {
             proxy_pass https://unicorn_domain;
          break;
       }

      if ($request_uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)\?[0-9]+$") {
        expires max;
        break;
     }

   }
}
```

But My application's home page is built mainly using javascript and it has more than one buttons which popup ajax windows which contains some forms by click action.Here comes the problem. When we are configuring the ssl to the site the windows are not popping up. It is only happening in the home page. In inside pages the functionality is working.Can anyone help me to find out the solution.

Thank You,
Regards

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript url's in your application like `<script src="#"></script>`

Comment: @menon , did it work for you now. As I am facing same issue.

Comment: @manish, can you check for javascripts the host scheme is http:// rather than https://

Comment: thanks @Menon, I solved and end up with below solution I written in answer. (y) . It worked just awesome for me.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#default-headers)

In `config/application.rb`:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
  'Access-Control-Request-Method' => '*'
})
```